# cmake `target_sources` finds sources but not headers

Tags: cmake

Trying to add includes as part of the target sources:

```
set(MY_HEADER_FILES my_header.h)
add_library(my_lib STATIC "")
target_include_directories(my_lib PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../inc/)
target_sources(my_lib PRIVATE ${MY_SOURCE_FILES} ${MY_HEADER_FILES})
```

Which throws:

```
Cannot find source file: my_header.h
```

Removing the addition of the header files and leaving just the sources builds just fine:

```
target_sources(my_lib PRIVATE ${MY_SOURCE_FILES})
```

What can be the issue?

I know adding in the include files as dependencies is really just a nice to have, but I'm confused as to why cmake can't seem to find them - I've ensured that I'm adding in the correct directory (else the code  doesn't compile), so it seems the issue is in `target_sources` not in the include directories, but if that's the case, why can't cmake find the files?

Comment: Just curious: Why you are specifying source files for the library in `target_sources` command, when you can specify them in the `add_library` call which creates the library? Normally, `target_sources` is used only for INTERFACE or other special kind of libraries.

Answer (score 2):

When a *header* file is specified as a *source* one (in `target_sources`, `add_executable` or `add_library` command), CMake uses the same principles to find the header, as the other sources.

That is, `include_directories` does NOT help CMake to find the header specified in the sources list.

Either use absolute path to the header:

```
target_sources(my_lib PRIVATE ${MY_SOURCE_FILES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../inc/my_header.h)
```

or use a path, relative to the current *source* or *binary* directory:

```
target_sources(my_lib PRIVATE ${MY_SOURCE_FILES} ../inc/my_header.h)
```